# Contract in bsctestnet cannot be verified

Tags: binance, verify, remix, bscscan

I tried to deploy my tokens on BSC testnet using Remix, but I always get an error when I verify. I tried a lot of methods, but still no solution. In fact the generated Bytecodes are not wrong, but I don't know why they wouldn't match.

[Solidity code verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HCHS.png)

[Compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gw0K.png)

This is the address of the contract：[0xf55d321ae5978b002c99bc853a208fae1a4b0ffb](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xf55d321ae5978b002c99bc853a208fae1a4b0ffb)

The address of the library used is:
`0x17382221cdE0e4F17806371d4B79Cb1b8d9958aD`
name：IterableMapping

code: https://gist.github.com/87302380/232d98a925cfe591610c49295c077c98

The code is from Dogeback, I just modified some of the addresses on the test net. The rest is exactly the same. Can anyone help me?